# Angular Universal npm run serve:universal getting error: ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I built an Angular Universal project from Angular 5, and when I run

```
npm run serve:universal
```

I'm getting error:
"ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined" at following files:

```
at new n (\dist-server\main.bundle.js:1:4483078)
at _createClass (\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10969:20)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10945:26)
at resolveNgModuleDep (node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10930:17)
at NgModuleRef_.get (\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12167:16)
at resolveDep (\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12657:45)
at createClass (\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12527:32)
at createDirectiveInstance (\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12364:37)
at createViewNodes (\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:13822:53)
```

Please give me an solution to resolve it. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using jQuery in any of your components?

Comment: No, I don't. It's come from the third library I added on my project.